# A problem with an elementary function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-functions

Prove or disprove:

For every $n\in\mathbb N$ there exist $x_n\in (10^n,+\infty)$ such that $f(x_n)<10^{-n}$ where $f(x)=(x \sin x - \cos^2 x)^2 x^6 + x^2 \cos^8 x.$

Comment: Thus - if this HW, please tag it as such. You should add what you've tried as well.

Comment: No, this is much harder than homework, although it maybe doesn´t look hard.

Comment: You still haven't stated where the problem is from, or what you've tried.

Comment: What could I try, I do not know of a method that could solve this. Well, I did change the variable x to 1/x and plotted it so that I see how it behaves at infinity by seeing how it behaves at zero with this change of variables.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28%28%28%28sin%281%2Fx%29%29%2Fx%29-%28cos%281%2Fx%29%29%5E2%29%5E2%29%2F%28x%5E6%29%2B%28%28cos%281%2Fx%29%5E8%29%2F%28x%5E2%29

Comment: I think that this is so hard that maybe I would offer a bounty of 500 if I had enough reputation.

Comment: **You still haven't stated where the problem is from**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We answer the question somewhat reluctantly, since there is undoubtedly a typo.

Let $n=3$, for no good reason. We show that there is **no** $x_n \gt 1000$ at which our function is $\lt 1/1000$.

For note from $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1$ that one of $\cos^2 x$ or $\sin^2 x$ is $\ge 1/2$.

If $\cos^2 x\ge 1/2$, then our expression is greater than $(1000)^2(1/2)^4$.  This is because the second term is greater than $(1000)^2(1/2)^4$, and the first term is non-negative.

If $\sin^2 x \ge 1/2$, then our expression is $\ge (500\sqrt{2}-1)^2(1000)^6$.

So for all $x\gt 1000$, our function is quite large, much larger than $1/1000$.

Comment: 1)If $cos^2x≥1/2$, then our expression is greater than $(1000)^2(1/2)^4$

I agree with this.

2) If $sin^2x≥1/2$, then our expression is $≥(5002√2−1)^2(1000)^6$

I do not agree with this.

I do not agree because if $sin^2x≥1/2$ then $sinx$ can be negative and $cosx$ can be arbitrarily small and because of that the expression $(x \sin x - \cos^2 x)^2 x^6$ could be close to zero and, simultaneously, $x^2 \cos^8 x$ could be close to zero, so the proof is not fine.

Comment: Or the proof is fine but my line of reasoning is not.

Comment: But if you are correct then I need an explanation of this, I changed the variable from x to 1/x to see how f(x) behaves at infinity by seeing how f(1/x) behaves at zero, and I plotted and got this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28%28%28%28sin%281%2Fx%29%29%2Fx%29-%28cos%281%2Fx%29%29%5E2%29%5E2%29%2F%28x%5E6%29%2B%28%28cos%281%2Fx%29%5E8%29%2F%28x%5E2%29

Is the process of this change of variable allowed and if it is why do I get this picture? I am really interested why?

Comment: Now the proof looks fine to me, but my line of reasoning not.

Comment: @Thus:  if $\sin x$ is negative it is less than $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$.  The factor $x$ makes it dominate over the $\cos x$ term, then it gets squared and is greater than 500.  It is still large.

Comment: @Thus: if $|\sin x|\ge 1/\sqrt{2}$, then the term $x\sin x$ has absolute value $\ge 500\sqrt{2}$. Always, $\cos^2 x$ is between $0$ and $1$. If $x\sin x$ is negative, then for sure $|x\sin x-\cos ^2 x\ge $500\sqrt{2}$. If $\sin x$ is positive, we get $\ge $500\sqrt{2}-1$. Actually, can replace the $-1$ by $-1/2$, but that doesn't change things much.

Comment: You two, thank you, I derived this function f from another function g that should be equivalent to f in the sense that the answer to the problem is affirmative, but you proved that it is not affirmative, so I really must dive into the process of valuating that method and improving it.

Comment: You might ask the question that this originally came from, since you may have made manipulations that were not quite right. But there is no doubt that in the question as asked, our function is big when $x$ is big.

Comment: Yes, the real problem lies in the manipulations, I must take some time to improve my method, and if it would work it could be the case that I could show that limits for some class of functions doesn`t exist.